# Referencing Local File, How to Receive Resources.NotFoundException?

Tags: android, json, exception

Given the following example (below) that will load a json file locally. Is there a chance of Resources.NotFoundException? If you reference a file that does not exist you receive a compile error. Furthermore, lets say that you somehow get passed the compile error, is managing this exception worth it? Presuming that you want to know when there is an issue like this (without masking/handling it)?

```
public static String loadJsonFromAsset(@NonNull Context context, int id) {
    String json;
    // open a data stream for reading a raw resource
    InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(id);
    try {
        // estimate of the number of bytes that can be read (or skipped over) from this
        // input stream
        byte[] buffer = new byte[is.available()];
        is.read(buffer);
        // constructs a new String by decoding the specified array of bytes using the specified
        // charset set String representation of json
        json = new String(buffer, UTF);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Logger.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Logger.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return json;
}
```

If it is the case that this needs to be handled, should inputStream be checked for null? Because the lint warnings will come up saying that it is an impossibility for inputStream to be null. But if you pass in an id that does not exist, it is a possibility. Which, again, leads me to believe that Resources.NotFoundException is a useless check because compile exception prevents the scenario all together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ResourceNotFoundException for id 0x0000 is caused if you have resource identifiers as raw-s480, raw-hdpi and so on, and trying to reach one file trough a device that does not met any especified qualifier.

You can also add a default folder (without qualifiers like `raw`) to users fallback if they dont met any other specific requirements

Comment: Hmmmm, I see. OK, then its settled. I will include that exception to my catch. Thanks!

Comment: Note that the line that throws it is outside the try/catch ```context.getResources().openRawResource(id);```

Comment: You can also add a default folder (without qualifiers like ```raw```) to users fallback if they dont met any other specific requirements

Comment: Great suggestions!